# There is a php ORM which is similar to Rails ActiveRecord?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, cakephp

I'm designing an e-commerce database for a school project that require usage of cakePHP.
The ORM « attempt » of cake (yeah, it's not really an ORM) doesn't fit my needs.

I tried doctrine 2, I'm not convinced by the complex DSL and some crazy behaviors.

What I'm searching is an ORM that make associations effort-less and use conventions like we can do it with Rails ActiveRecord.

Because of complexity of an e-commerce database, I can't test everything and advices on doing that in PHP will be appreciated

Comment: google php activerecord its result number one

Comment: this is not because there is results on google that a better one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to share our experience with [PHP ActiveRecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/).

We are using it in production on a commercial web app for 2 years. We chose it for its unmatched simplicity and because it uses PHP5.3 features to provide nice RoR-like methods.

For 2 years we never had any significant issues with the library. We update it from time to time to keep up to date and pretty happy with it.

PHP ActiveRecord won't suite everybody since, well, it's ActiveRecord, not true ORM. But as you are specifically looking for RoR-like ActiveRecord solution in PHP, look no further.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's [Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) is nice, it can take a little bit of work to [get it standalone](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=Laravel+Eloquent+ORM+standalone) but it's worth it.

Comment: Eloquent is very interesting, but it's quite complicated to get validations working.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to search for composer ActiveRecord packages, there are dozens of them:

One of them which says it was inspired by RoR: https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord

There are dozens of them: https://packagist.org/search/?q=activerecord

Or even try ruby on rails in your search https://packagist.org/search/?q=activerecord%20ruby%20on%20rails

Try at least a bit of your own research before asking questions, as well as showing what you have found and tried.

Comment: especially considering your first link is the same as the one I posted in comments yet he says its not been touched since june 2010 however looking at the git there's clearly updates from just a month ago on there oO

Comment: @Dave it may be someoene's submitting pull requests and he's just quickly merging them or he's a lazy one to update the info :)

Comment: probably a little of both but just because its not been stable released any time soon it doesn't mean it doesn't still function correctly

Comment: I never said it doesn't work correctly, but I prefer to learn/work with active softwares for new projects. So now I will read both phpactiverecord & eloquent doc to find which one can fit my needs and make cleaner code as possible

Comment: @badfoo I work day to day with eloquent and it is my favorite ORM implementation, but your question was the ORM that's most similar to RoR AR, so I'm not suggesting it.